# Why is Double Swing better than Frenzy?

Tags: diablo-ii, diablo-ii-resurrected

I try to understand the difference between the Barbarian skills Double Swing and Frenzy with the [Diablo 2 Character Planner](https://d2.maxroll.gg/d2planner/).

The items in my example are:

```
Death Colossus Sword(Equipped)385% ed eth
Fortitude Archon Plate(Equipped)1572 def 1.5 life/lvl 30@
Grief Phase Blade(Equipped)40 ias 400 dmg -25% psn pierce 15 laek
Arreat's Face(Equipped)6 ll 200% def + um
Dracul's Grasp(Equipped)10 ll 120% def 15 str 10 laek
Gore Rider(Equipped)200% def
Highlord's Wrath(Equipped)
Nature's Peace(Equipped)30 pr 11 dr
Raven Frost(Equipped)250 ar 20 dex
Thundergod's Vigor(Equipped)200% def
```

These are the skills: I maxed out Double Swing and Frenzy with all bonus skills except Berserk.

[image: skills]

And these are the calculations:

[image: calculations]

The calculation says that Double Swing makes 32k damage per second while Frenzy does only 31K damage per second. I think the reason is that Double Swing does 5 hits per second while Frenzy does only 3.5 hits per second. And this is what I do not understand. Although Frenzy adds attack speed and Double Swing does not, the number of hits is lower.  Even if I increase the Frenzy stacks to 25 the number of hits is below 4.

The reason may be hidden in the tables, I do not know how to read them.

Can anybody explain how to read the attack rate tables and why Double Swing makes more hits per second than Frenzy?

Comment: Old comment here mentioned a hidden IAS bonus for double swing, which may be why it has more hits per second: https://www.diabloii.net/forums/threads/double-swing-faster-than-frenzy.680673/  Unsure about accuracy though so posting as comment.

Comment: There is a cap on frames per attack, so increasing attack speed infinitely won't increase your damage, for example. The calculation is insane, but essentially frenzy maxes out its damage because you can only effectively attack a certain number of times per a certain number of frames.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud The table seems to say something different. Frenzy is not at one end of the table.